Bazzite WSL Distro For UE 5.4 Clang Cross-Compile Testing
So basically I would like to create a WSL Bazzite distribution to test the Unreal Engine Cross-Compilation tools for testing. I found this container image hoping I would be able to export as a tar then import to WSL Directly unfortunately the container doesn't start for me.
https://hub.docker.com/r/azuras/bazzite
I was following this video for the UE 5 cross-compile functionality.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MVm5got0RMY
Is this even possible? If so can someone explain how to convert the Bazzite ISO into a Tar for WSL Import.
Thank you in advance!
